# How do i use ipfw to allow some sites and block all sites

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro, ipfw

I am new to ipfw, my requirement is like that, once application launches,i need to read the certain application parameter and depending upon them, i should be able to allow some site and block others,

I am thinking of using ipfw as its i might need to run them in admin privilege,

the reason behind choose www.slashdot.org is its always giving me static ip "216.34.181.48"

assuming ,  i want to allow www.slashdot.org and block all other site, this is what i have tried ,

```
sudo ipfw flush
sudo ipfw add allow ip from me to 216.34.181.48
sudo ipfw add allow tcp from me to 216.34.181.48 
sudo ipfw add deny tcp from me to any 
sudo ipfw add deny ip from me to any
```

but its blocking www.slashdot.org site also,

Are these rules correct or any correction required ?

Comment: Are you able to connect to http://216.34.181.48/ directly?

Comment: if i do ping 216.34.181.48 it connects,but if in the browser i type http://216.34.181.48 it doesn't work